# input button no longer working when I add a style class

Tags: html, css, class, button, input

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button2").click(function(){
    alert("clicked")
  });
});
```

```css
[type='button'].button2 {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 31%;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://google.com">
 <input type="button" class="button2" value="Start Browsing!" />
 </form>
```

My button is not clickable anymore when I add a class to it. How do I fix this? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
`<form action="https://google.com">
 <input type="button" class="button2" value="Start Browsing!" />
 </form>`
```

**CSS**

```
`[type='button'].button2 {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 31%;
    font-weight: bold;
 }`
```

I tried adding a 'div' instead of a class but this also didn't work.

I have another button on the page in which I'm using <input type="submit"... but I want this button to be styled differently to that one so changed this one to submit isn't an option

Comment: You can give it a different class, or if it is unique, you can try ID in CSS and assign it to the button you want to style differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'not clickable'? I tried to add a JavaScript function, and it's showing that the button click action is still being called as you can see below:

CSS

```
<style>
[type='button'].button2 {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 31%;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
```

HTML with JS Function

```
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Start Browsing!" onclick="alert('click button')" />
```

if you tried above code actually the button already clicked and showing the alert.

if you mean by 'not clickable' is the button standard hover effect, you may use below CSS for your button hover effect

```
<style>
[type='button'].button2 {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 31%;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 [type='button'].button2:hover{
    background: #E7E7E7
 }
 
</style>
```

and if you want to execute the form action by pressing the button,
you may need to change the type from **button** to **submit**

as below

```
<form action="https://google.com">
 <input type="submit" class="button2" value="Start Browsing!" />
 </form>
```

and the css should be something like below

```
input[type=submit].button2 { YOUR CSS HERE }
```

Hope its help you :)

Comment: Thanks Jacky! The problem I was having is that when I changed the type to submit, the styling was the same as another submit button I have on the same page. However, I have added a div to the button and its working well now! Many thanks :)